# Moving Identity Modules outside the ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Identity 2.0

I moved the Identity 2.0 classes (classes defined in `Model/IdentityModel.cs` and `Startup/IdentityConfig.cs`) to a class Library because all my models need to reside outside the website, and so does the `ApplicationUser` class.

After moving the classes I had to install `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` nuget.

Now when I run the application, I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

[Stack Trace here](http://pastebin.com/yNk9aWLA)

I don't really know what went wrong and where. Everything seems to work well till `Startup.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by just deleting the database, and letting EF create a new one for me. The `ApplicationDbInitializer`'s Seed() was called appropriately and everything worked fine.